# Installing QCMBundle - The child node "driver" must be configured

Tags: symfony, sylius

when i try to install the bundle https://github.com/avoo/QcmCoreBundle , i have the error

[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationExcept
 ion]
   The child node "driver" at path "qcm_core" must be configured.

This is my app/config/config.yml

```
imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
- { resource: security.yml }
- { resource: services.yml }
- { resource: @QcmCoreBundle/Resources/config/core.yml }
parameters:
     locale: fr
framework:
     #esi:             ~
     translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
     secret:          "%secret%"
     router:
         resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
         strict_requirements: ~
     form:            ~
     csrf_protection: ~
     validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
     templating:
         engines: ['twig']
         #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
         default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
        fragments:       ~
        http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm 
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: CrowdRiseBundle\Entity\Membre
    registration:
        form:
            type: crowd_rise_user_registration

qcm_core:
    user_class: CrowdRiseBundle\Entity\Projetcs
    website_name: Qcm Demo 
    configuration:
        max_questions: 40 
        question_level: ["beginner", "senior", "jedi"] 
        answers_max: 5 
        timeout: 2400 
        time_per_question: 60
```

Comment: try adding  `driver: orm` under qcm_core

Comment: i have tried it , but it doesn't recongnize orm !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QcmCoreBundle uses Sylius ResourceBundle, which requires a driver for the database. In this case, there is [only one supported](https://github.com/avoo/QcmCoreBundle/blob/b0eb6d821070d1b8c5e644db97932c83abb37ab1/QcmCoreBundle.php#L24) - this would be:

```
qcm_core:
    # ...
    driver: doctrine/orm
```